# Some Simple Errors With a IRC Bot Made With Perl

Tags: perl, cpan, irc, bots

I'm following a tutorial called [Programming IRC Bots In Perl](http://wholok.com/irc/) to make a simple IRC bot for my channel at Abjects server, the problem is that I'm getting some weird errors. Take a look:

> Nathan-Camposs-MacBook-Pro:Desktop Nathan$ ./bot.pl
>   ./bot.pl: line 1: use: command not found
>   ./bot.pl: line 4: my: command not found
>   ./bot.pl: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
>
>   ./bot.pl: line 8:`my $conn = $irc->newconn('
>   Nathan-Camposs-MacBook-Pro:Desktop Nathan$

With this code:

```
use Net::IRC;

# create the IRC object
my $irc = new Net::IRC;

# Create a connection object.  You can have more than one "connection" per
# IRC object, but we'll just be working with one.
my $conn = $irc->newconn(
 Server   => shift || 'summer.abjects.net',
 # Note: IRC port is normally 6667, but my firewall won't allow it
 Port  => shift || '6667',
 Nick  => 'iBot',
 Ircname  => 'I\'ve bee built by iNathan!',
 Username => 'iBot'
);

# We're going to add this to the conn hash so we know what channel we
# want to operate in.
$conn->{channel} = shift || '#MobilePassion';

sub on_connect {

 # shift in our connection object that is passed automatically
 my $conn = shift;

 # when we connect, join our channel and greet it
 $conn->join($conn->{channel});
 $conn->privmsg($conn->{channel}, 'Hello everyone!');
 $conn->{connected} = 1;
}

# The end of MOTD (message of the day), numbered 376 signifies we've connect
$conn->add_handler('376', \&on_connect);

sub on_join {

 # get our connection object and the event object, which is passed
 # with this event automatically
 my ($conn, $event) = @_;

 # this is the nick that just joined
 my $nick = $event->{nick};
 # say hello to the nick in public
 $conn->privmsg($conn->{channel}, "Hello, $nick!");
}

$conn->add_handler('join', \&on_join);

$irc->start();
```

What should I do to correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition, and I'm sure you've seen and heard this before somewhere, but do yourself a favor and don't use `Net::IRC`... It's been dead in the water for a self advertised 7 years.

The new recommendation is to use `POE::Component::IRC` or some variant.  While `POE::Component::IRC` offers you the most control, flexibility, and visibility into the functions of the bot, a much easier approach is `Bot::BasicBot`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: But how I can change my code to make it work with `POE::Component::IRC`?

Comment: There are several `POE::Component::IRC` IRC bot tutorials around, I surprised you actually found one that wasn't for this module.  Luckily, you don't have much code in your existing example, and porting would not be too much of a challenge.  The same principles apply with registering hooks to certain IRC-related events, and writing the functions to service those hooks/events.

Comment: As well, a sample POE::Component::IRC bot can be found here: http://www.supportforums.net/showthread.php?tid=10989, documentation at http://search.cpan.org/~hinrik/POE-Component-IRC-6.52/lib/POE/Component/IRC.pm

Comment: Thanks very much. Also, I've improved the formatting of your answer :)

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

at the top. /bin/sh doesn't generally understand Perl, which is what you're seeing.

Also, I would recommend:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Comment: That would be another question.  Ask it as a question rather than as a comment, so that people can find the answers more easily.  (But as a starter for 10, get http://cpanmin.us/, then cpanm Net::IRC, then read the instructions.)

Answer (score 1):

In reference to http://freetexthost.com/wdmcihuvxx, you're missing the Net library. Depending on which OS you're on you have multiple ways of getting it - or just use CPAN.

Comment: I got this message form CPAN: `Refusing to install due to lack of confirmation at Makefile.PL line 28, <STDIN> line 1.  
Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL]`

Comment: Did you answer yes (or whatever it asks you to) when it asked?

Comment: Have you started it with 'perl Makefile.PL' ?

Comment: No need to (I usually directly use IO::Socket though). Run the libnet installation with 'perl Makefile.PL'. You can find that file after having downloaded the lib archive from CPAN.